# Not able to display log level field into KIBANA

Tags: logstash

I am not able to display log level field into KIBANA.

**Logstash conf file**
[image: Logstash conf file]

**Kibana page**

[image: Kibana page]

I want to display log level as field value in KIBANA so that we can easily filter all list of message who has level as error and warning.

Could some please help me to figure out my mistake ?

Comment: I'm downvoting you for using pictures instead of copy/pasting your configuration into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `mutate{add_field => {"logfield" => %{LOGLEVEL:level}} }`. This filter will add a field named logfield and try to give it the value of the field named `LOGLEVEL:level`. Since such field does not exist, logstash just put `%{LOGLEVEL:level}`.

If the grok filter works correctly (no tag `_grokparsefailure`), you should have a field `level` with your log level. To use it in your mutate/add_field:

```
mutate{add_field => {"logfield" => %{:level}} }
```